# Fluent nhibernate mapping nested properties "cannot find getter"

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Ok, this may be a double-question. I have a class `User`, which contains a property `Location` of type `UserLocation`. At first, I was mapping **both** the `User` class **and** the `UserLocation` class and storing them both in the db, but that didn't make a lot of sense to me, since the only purpose for `UserLocation` is to be a part of `User`. Anyway, now, my mapping looks like this:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughLowerCaseField().GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Location.Address);
            Map(x => x.Location.City);
            Map(x => x.Location.State);
            Map(x => x.Location.ZipCode);
        }
    }
```

But I get the error "Could not find getter for `UserLocation.Address`". I also get a bunch of casting errors because it seems NHibernate is still generating a computed class for `UserLocation`. So I guess the question is **what is the best way to reference a non-mapped custom class from inside a mapped one**.

Oh, just to add, I'm pretty sure that `UserLocation` isn't being mapped **anywhere**. I even tried taking the reference to it out of the `User` mapping, and I still get casting errors trying to convert the computed class to the real one. I cannot possibly understand why there would even be a computed type at this point..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have there is a [component](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#components). Components are mapped separately in NHibernate.

Your Fluent NHibernate mapping should look like this:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughLowerCaseField()
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Component(x => x.Location,
            loc =>
            {
                loc.Map(x => x.Address);
                loc.Map(x => x.City);
                loc.Map(x => x.State);
                loc.Map(x => x.ZipCode); 
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Small typo, hehehe, it's not "muchos", but "muchas", in spanish, because "gracias" is a word in "female gender". "Muchas gracias".